# Java: difference between < and <= for long integer for 9223372036854775807L

Tags: java, precision

When I run the following code in JVM, I am unable to understand why it behaves like this. 
As per my understanding, `< x` operator should go till `x-1`.

```
  public class LongQuestion {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

        if(9223372036854775807L < Math.pow(2,63)) {
            System.out.println("True");                            // DOES NOT GET PRINTED
        }

         if(9223372036854775807L <= Math.pow(2,63) - 1 ) {
            System.out.println("Also True");                       // THIS GETS PRINTED
        }

    }

}
```

I want to understand why Java behaves like this.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.pow` is declared as

```
public static double pow​(double a, double b)
```

So we are dealing with doubles. `Math.pow(2,63)` is "`2.0d ^ 63.0d`" (power, not eor). As `double` is 64 bits in total, changing the value 60 odd bits below the most significant bit will not change the value. So `Math.pow(2,63) == Math.pow(2,63) - 1`, which is also `(double)9223372036854775807L`.

Making the implicits casts implicit in the first `if`.

```
    if((double)9223372036854775807L < Math.pow(2.0d,63.0d)) {
        System.out.println("True");                            // DOES NOT GET PRINTED
    }
```

Both left and right side of `<` are `9.223372036854776E18`, so `false`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?  I am unable to understand this.

Comment: *"eor"*? More commonly called "xor".

Comment: To clarify, the 64-bit number `9223372036854775807L` becomes `9.223372036854776E18` because a 64-bit `double` only has 53 bits of precision.

Comment: @Andreas XOR (/ˌɛks ˈɔːr/ or /ˈzɔːr/), EOR, EXOR, ⊻, ⩒, ⩛, ⊕, ↮, and ≢. (Source: Wikipedia!) EOR is the mnemonic used in 6502 and ARM assembly language, so it'll do for me.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Wow, the old 6502, now that brings back memories... Anyway, most modern programming languages uses `xor`, including Java, where both [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#xor-java.math.BigInteger-) and [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#xor-java.util.BitSet-) has `xor(...)` methods. There are no `eor(...)` methods in the Java Runtime Library.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will help you understand it:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Long.MAX_VALUE is " + Long.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println("Math.pow(2, 63) is " + Math.pow(2, 63));
        System.out.println("Math.pow(2, 63) - 1 is " + (Math.pow(2, 63) - 1));
        System.out.println("(long)Math.pow(2, 63) is " + (long) Math.pow(2, 63));
        System.out.println("(long)(Math.pow(2, 63) - 1) is " + (long) (Math.pow(2, 63) - 1));

        if (9223372036854775807L < Math.pow(2, 63)) {
            System.out.println("9223372036854775807L < Math.pow(2, 63)");
        }

        if (9223372036854775807L <= Math.pow(2, 63)) {
            System.out.println("9223372036854775807L <= Math.pow(2, 63)");
        }

        if (9223372036854775807L <= Math.pow(2, 63) - 1) {
            System.out.println("9223372036854775807L <= Math.pow(2, 63) - 1");
        }

        if (9223372036854775807L < (long) Math.pow(2, 63)) {
            System.out.println("9223372036854775807L < (long)Math.pow(2, 63)");
        }

        if (9223372036854775807L <= (long) Math.pow(2, 63)) {
            System.out.println("9223372036854775807L <= (long)Math.pow(2, 63)");
        }

        if (9223372036854775807L <= (long) Math.pow(2, 63) - 1) {
            System.out.println("9223372036854775807L <= (long)Math.pow(2, 63) - 1");
        }

        if (9223372036854775807L <= (long) (Math.pow(2, 63) - 1)) {
            System.out.println("9223372036854775807L <= (long)(Math.pow(2, 63) - 1)");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Long.MAX_VALUE is 9223372036854775807
Math.pow(2, 63) is 9.223372036854776E18
Math.pow(2, 63) - 1 is 9.223372036854776E18
(long)Math.pow(2, 63) is 9223372036854775807
(long)(Math.pow(2, 63) - 1) is 9223372036854775807
9223372036854775807L <= Math.pow(2, 63)
9223372036854775807L <= Math.pow(2, 63) - 1
9223372036854775807L <= (long)Math.pow(2, 63)
9223372036854775807L <= (long)(Math.pow(2, 63) - 1)
```

Comment: I am sorry I am unable to understand how this answers the question?

Comment: Thanks, Can you please also explain why it behaves this way?